# How to keep just HEAD of local experimental branch

Tags: git

I have an experimental branch (which is *not* on any remote repository) and I want to keep only it's HEAD before I merge it with master

```
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate

* c44824d (HEAD -> experiment) amazing experiment
* 66650f0 embarrasing commit
* 0a0289d embarrasing commit
* cc0e9b6 embarrasing commit
* a9e76f0 embarrasing commit
* be94f13 embarrasing commit
* ac6a3f6 (heroku/master, master) amazing commit
* d2c5a8c amazing commit
* d5cc13c amazing commit
```

I'd like it to look like this

```
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate

* c44824d (HEAD -> experiment) amazing experiment
* ac6a3f6 (heroku/master, master) amazing commit
* d2c5a8c amazing commit
* d5cc13c amazing commit
```

I don't need (or want) to preserve any of the experimental branch's history

Comment: Are you trying to describe a *squash*?

Comment: I looked into squash but it seems like it's reversible with reflog

Comment: So is the answer you've accepted, it doesn't immediately delete all of those commits. Note that's only *locally*. And also so what?

Comment: oh, maybe I don't fully understand how reflog and squash works. can a squashed branch that's been merged with master and pushed to remote not be reversed by someone else that clones it? there are just some commits in the experiment branch that I'd rather not see the light of day

Comment: You don't push everything reachable via the reflog to the remote, only everything reachable from the ref you push. Also if you only want that last *diff*, not the *result*, you can just cherry-pick the last commit.

Comment: hmm... I've never used cherry-pick before but it looks like it would work here. so just basically `git checkout master` and `git cherry-pick c44824d` in this example. if i delete the experiment branch is there any difference in the final result from `git reset --soft master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple:

```
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "amazing experiment"
```

There you are